# Numpy: constructing a 3D array from a 1D array

Tags: arrays, numpy

Assume a 1D array `A` is given. Is there an easy way to construct a 3D array `B`, such that `B[i,j,k] = A[k]` for all i,j,k? You can assume that the shape of B is prescribed, and that `B.shape[2] = A.shape[0]`.

Comment: Do you mean you want to tile the array? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
>>> k = 4
>>> a = np.arange(k)
>>> j = 3
>>> i = 2
>>> np.tile(a,j*i).reshape((i,j,k))
array([[[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]],

       [[0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3],
        [0, 1, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: You can replace `np.tile(np.tile(a,j),i).reshape((i,j,k))` with `np.tile(a, i*j).reshape((i,j,k))`

Comment: I removed my `np.tile(A,(i,j,1))` suggestion because it had terrible performance for large arrays. Do you know why `np.tile(A,i*j).reshape(i,j,k)` scales so much better?

Comment: @MLW:  I typed `numpy.source(numpy.tile)` and saw that `tile` calls `reshape` and `repeat` for each element in the `reps` tuple.  `reshape` returns a copy which means re-allocating all that memory each time.  Seems poorly implemented to me.

Answer (score 4):

Another easy way to do this is simple assignment -- broadcasting will automatically do the right thing:

```
i = 2
j = 3
k = 4
a = numpy.arange(k)
b = numpy.empty((i, j, k))
b[:] = a
print b
```

prints

```
[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]]

 [[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in enumerate(A): B[:,:,k] = v
```

Comment: Isn't this very inefficient since it involves a slow for loop?

Comment: @celli It is O(n) on the size of `A`, and no algorithm can do better than that because each element of `A` must be examined to perform the computation. Other answers have suggested that using `numppy.tile()` is a better option than a direct assignment. The solution I propose is clear and pythonic, and I expect NumPy to handle the assignments efficiently (perhaps with `tile()`), but one would have to measure (time it) to know.